# Apache Solr , How to move index data to different cluster

Tags: apache, solr

We are having two solr cluster but only one is active at a time.
If we move the Index data to different cluster with same collection name.

Would that work instead of re-indexing the data alltogether.

Regards.

Comment: did you try it yourself? did you try anything?

Comment: I have not tried it , But do u any expertise on the same

Answer (score 0):

With a standalone Solr it works fine if you copy the index data along with the configuration.

We have used it before several times to either archive data or move to different nodes.

There are better ways though, for example using the ReplicationHandler but that has a bit more complexity:
https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/index-replication.html